# About providing fractions

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I write fractions in my answers and questions? How do I write any mathematical expression ? I have tried using x/y type of expressions but it does not work.

Please tell me how to do it. Will it need any special HTML code?

I am new to the site, so please be a bit expletive.

Comment: Try $\frac{x}{y}$

Comment: How do I write mathematical expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/804/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4080/2451 , and links therein.